# Programming WordPress to Send an Email on Registration Form Submit?

Tags: email, user-registration

*(**Moderator's note:** The original title was: "submit button in wordpress.")*

I'd like to create a registration form to send an email.

I've tried [Contact Form 7](http://contactform7.com/) but I would like to use my own HTML `<form>`. I can do the entire coding but I just want to know the code for the *"submit"* button so that the registrations goes directly to my admin email ID as I don't think the normal HTML code for the submit button will work.

Can anyone help me out in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you might be able to do something on the client with jQuery I think your best bet would be to use the [**Post/Redirect/Get Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) and submit your registration form via a `<form method='post'>` action.

The code after the screenshot below is a *"[**Page Template**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates)"* for a *"[**Page**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Pages_in_a_Nutshell)"* illustrates how to achieve what you've asked for with WordPress. Copy the code to your theme directory as `page-contact-form.php` *(or some other name you like better)* and then create a page that has template set to *"Contact Form"* as you see in the screenshot *(note I kept the page template as simple as possible to illustrate the technique; you'll typically have a lot more code in your real live page templates):*

[image: Using a Page Template in WordPress 3.0]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101203-012104.png))</sub>

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: Contact Form
*/
define('ADMIN_USER','mikeschinkel');
if (count($_POST)) {
  $admin_user = get_userdatabylogin(ADMIN_USER);
  $registered_email = $_POST['email'];
  wp_mail($admin_user->user_email,
    'New Site Registration',
    "New Site Registration:\n\tEmail: {$registered_email}.");
}
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (count($_POST)): ?>
    <p>Hey <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>, thanks for registering!</p>
<?php else: ?>
  <form method="post">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
  </form>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

After you've created your page with the above page template it might look something like this on your external site:

[image: Simple Registration Form for WordPress, Part 1]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101203-012931.png))</sub>

And this might be what it looks like after a visitor registers:

[image: Simple Registration Form for WordPress, Part 2]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101203-013134.png))</sub>

Comment: thanks for your answer
it solved my problem,
i have put this form in single.php, so that it appears after post ends
but i would like put this in a jquery section, i mean when after a user clicks on link like "Open" the a slide down jquery will show the form just like this example
http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

but when i try this by putting it into my file(single.php), my entire page is disturbed, i tried it by putting in header file but it is not working

Comment: @ntechi - To use jQuery+AJAX the techniques are completely different than to use HTTP POST. See http://bit.ly/gVCiWB http://bit.ly/h4Joh2 http://bit.ly/fMxKNe http://bit.ly/hD1y39 http://bit.ly/f1R7zV http://bit.ly/epoPYf

Comment: i have tried jquery code in a proper manner, here is the code and images
this is the image of my jquery code
http://i55.tinypic.com/rsfslh.jpg

and this is the image of my website sidebar, which is not proper
http://i52.tinypic.com/2gxe90p.jpg
in this the jquery is working, but just the sidebar is not proper
am i doing anything wrong??

Comment: @ntechi - Your question in the comments is evolving to be very different from the original question you asked on this page, and it's too hard to discuss in the comments. Ask another question here at WordPress Answers and be sure to give all the details. Not sure if I'll have time to answer it but I'm sure someone will *(and please, it will help if you use proper capitalization so it will be easier to read your question.)*